# How to know if an object from a relation exists in the database

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm using Symfony with Doctrine.

I have two classes defined, **Person** and **Student**, a relation one to one.

Each **Student** is related to a **Person**, but not every **Person** has a relation with a **Student**.

When I call ...

```
$person->getStudent();
```

... I always get and object, regardless some **Person**'s doesn't have a Student. How can I know it doesn't (the **Student**) exist in the database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think

```
$person->getStudent()->exists();
```

should do it. At least according to the [Doctrine API documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/Doctrine_Record/1_2).
The object you get is probably some kind of Null record.

Comment: @Felix thanks! But it would be better if it returned a `null` when a record doesn't exist ¿isn't it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kiewic: Yes I also had problems with this and expected a `null` value instead of an object. If you find the answer useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`Doctrine_Record::relatedExists()`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/working-with-models.html#id11), which is kind of a complement to [`hasReference()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_record.html#hasReference())

You use it like this:

```
if ($person->relatedExists('Student'))
```

Comment: Yes, using the `$person->relatedExists('Student')` way is much better than doing `$person->Student->exists();` as the latter will actually create a new "blank" object in memory, attach it to the `$person" and will insert it as a blank row when/if you call `$person->save();`

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty new method (I think since Doctrine 1.2): `$person->hasReference("Student");` returns a boolean for whether there is actually a Student associated to the person, no matter whether it was saved already or not in database, and as desired without creating a new Student record.
This call can be suitable in situations when application logic doesn't care about the persistence of the related object, e.g. while within a transaction (I guess).
Hope that helps a bit, cheers, RAPHAEL